# confused about why this coefficient of fourier series is defined as so

Tags: fourier-series, eigenfunctions

First quesiton solved!
The second question about this page is that, I am really confused about why the coefficient $C_n$ is defined like this, quotient of two vectors?
[image]

Comment: This happens when your function is a odd function i.e $f(-x)=-f(x)$

Comment: This last part is odd so it will be zero, but for real part you have to just solve the integration.

Comment: Yes, but after I calculated the integration, the real part is not $0$

Comment: when $f$ is even then $\int_{-l}^{l} f=2\int_{0}^{l} f$

Comment: $\int\limits_{-L}^L cos((n-m)\pi x/L) dx = \dfrac L {(n-m)\pi}sin((n-m)\pi x/L)|_{-L}^{L}$, and $\sin \pm k\pi=0$

Comment: So that is why I am confused, why the textbook says this integral is $0$?

Comment: it will zero, see the comment of @J.W.Tanner

Comment: Oh, I see! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_{-L}^L \cos((n-m)\pi x/L) dx = \dfrac L {(n-m)\pi}\sin((n-m)\pi x/L)\bigg|_{-L}^{L},\\$$

and $\sin \pm k\pi=0$, where $k=n-m$ is an integer.

Comment: Thanks a lot....